# MySQL: Stored procedures

Tags: mysql

We are at the beginning to build up our site. Maybe you should check it out first to understand our problem: [www.erasmusinn.com](http://erasmusinn.com)

Basically we are thinking about to use MySQL for stored procedures or not.
We only need to insert and update our database. Since we are planning to have thousands of database entities, it is very important that we use the most efficient way to update our database.

What do you think? Should we use MySQL?

Comment: Are you asking whether to use MySQL or not, or have you already decided to use MySQL and are asking whether to use stored procedures. You use stored procedures if you need to do multiple operations or queries with a single name.

Comment: Any decent SQL platform can handle millions of database entities. as @Barmar pointed out, stored procedures are helpful for doing the same operation repeatedly, and also can give a certain level of security. However there are lots of different ways to approach this. Rather than focusing on the most efficient, do something that works and you understand how to do, and worry about efficiency once you hit hundreds of thousands of users.

Comment: @Nico . . . Not only is the question primarily opinion based (a reason to close it), but it comes dangerously close to being an ad to get traffic to the site.

Answer (score -1):

Personally i would recommend PostgreSQL. It's free to use and easy to migrate from MySQL, and you can build your own functions, views, and have data relations.

Comment: it really depends on the technical ability of the team, personally I find MySQL Workbench to be much better, both have similar performance, either way this is super opinion-based.

Comment: @user1587985 . . . You are learning why opinion-based questions and product recommendations are disallowed from Stack Overflow.